# Post 1:N (one customer many phonenumbers) JSON Array to android and parse it in PHP

Tags: php, android, json, relation, one-to-many

I want to create a more complex JSON Array where a customer (which has a name) has many phonenumbers so that i can parse it in PHP and i need your help.

i.e.:

```
public Class ContactVO
{
    public String diplayname;
    public ArrayList<PhoneVO> phonenumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneVO>();
}


public Class PhoneVO
{
    public String number;
}
```

Can s.o. give me an example how to create the above 1:N structure as JSON Array and how to parse it via PHP?

I put everything in a ArrayList and added the GSON library to may project.

The result is:

```
[
  {"contact_id":"1","displayname":"Bjyyyyy","phonenumbers":[{"number":"066-6228"}]},  
  {"contact_id":"2","displayname":"Rainer Unsinn","phonenumbers":[{"number":"(066) 214-52"}]},
  {"contact_id":"3","displayname":"Dieter karpenstein","phonenumbers":[{"number":"06621716669"}]},
  {"contact_id":"4","displayname":"Sido","phonenumbers":[{"number":"(085) 011-1555"}]},
  {"contact_id":"5","displayname":"Jochen Müller","phonenumbers":[{"number":"01773313261"}]}
]
```

How should the receiving PHP File lookslike to parse that?

Comment: "more complex"? What's wrong with writing a `toJSON()` method in `ContactVO` in the format, `{"displayname": [PhoneVO.number]}`, and then using `json_decode($JSON_STRING)` in PHP?

Comment: you probably will need json_decode function

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to show your friends numbers. Can I call 01773313261 and ask about Jochen ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking for the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function?

```
$fromPost = $_POST['contact'];
$object = json_decode($fromPost, true); // Read the doc to decide whether you want the "true" or not
var_dump($object);
```

**Edit:**
You could have something like that (not tested)

```
$string = '[
  {"contact_id":"1","displayname":"Bjyyyyy","phonenumbers":[{"number":"066-6228"}]},  
  {"contact_id":"2","displayname":"Rainer Unsinn","phonenumbers":[{"number":"(066) 214-52"}]},
  {"contact_id":"3","displayname":"Dieter karpenstein","phonenumbers":[{"number":"06621716669"}]},
  {"contact_id":"4","displayname":"Sido","phonenumbers":[{"number":"(085) 011-1555"}]},
  {"contact_id":"5","displayname":"Jochen Müller","phonenumbers":[{"number":"01773313261"}]}
]';

$decoded = json_decode($string);

foreach($decoded as $person) {
        echo $person['displayname'] . "\n";
        foreach($person['phonenumbers'] as $phone) {
                echo $phone['number'] . "\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you help me iterate through the result (see below)

Comment: I added an example (not tested)